# Advice on connecting heater directly to SP2 relay of PID controller?

Tags: temperature, control-system, pid-controller, heater

I have an old Omega CN-9121 PID Controller and a 105Watts 115V Fibre heater mantle with an inbuilt K-type CHromel-Alumel temperature thermocouple also attached into it. I plan to use the PID controller to control the temperature of the heater. Looking at the manual below:

[Manual for PID](https://assets.omega.com/manuals/M0575.pdf)

I decided that I wanted to use the inbuilt SP2 relay in the PID controller. From the wattage of the heater, I know it would draw a maximum of only 1A and is going to be below that. The SP2 output from the PID has a small 5V energized relay with 3A load capacity. I would like to know if it is safe to use the heater directly with the SP2 relay terminals of should I use the SP2 relay to run another AC relay for the heater?

[image: Heater]

[image: PID]
[image: PID rear]
[image: Specs]
[image: Relay- SP2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I decided that I wanted to use the inbuilt SP2 relay in the PID controller.

That's fine.

> From the wattage of the heater, I know it would draw a maximum of only 1A and is going to be below that.

That's fine too.

> The SP2 output from the PID has a small 5V energized relay with 3A load capacity.

I didn't read the manual (but have used Omega controllers in the past) and don't know how you figured out that it uses a 5 V relay coil internally but it's not that unlikely.

> I would like to know if it is safe to use the heater directly with the SP2 relay terminals of should I use the SP2 relay to run another AC relay for the heater?

[image]

*Figure 1. Waveform for short-period duty cycles from an SSR. Source: [LEDnique.com](http://lednique.com/opto-isolators-2/opto-triacs-zero-cross-work/).*

You can do either. For relay operation it would be normal to set the output duty cycle period to 5 s minimum. This is to reduce relay and contact wear. If your heater's thermal response is too fast and you require a shorter time then you should use the SSd output which will provide a 5 V signal for an SSR. This you can switch much more often - even down to 0.5 s but be aware that your SSR will, most likely, use zero-cross switching and that with very short periodic times you will be switching on for only a few mains cycles.